# Enable 2FA For Non-Primary Apple ID

Tags: apple-id, two-step-authentication

It seems the only way to enable two factor authentication on an Apple ID is by using an Apple device.

I can log into my non-primary Apple ID on the appleid.apple.com website but the instructions for enabling 2FA require that I enable it on an apple device. But this would mean I would need to remove my existing primary Apple ID first and set the Non-Primary to be the primary.

How can I enable 2FA for my Apple ID that is not the primary ID via the website?

Comment: Impossible, you need a physical device, also i've tried simulator - it didn't let me to connect iCloud.